# Can anybody identify from which order these nuns are?

Tags: catholicism, religious-orders, identify-this

[image]
Picture taken Eastbourne about 1900.

Comment: I'm guessing [Eastbourne, United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastbourne) and not [Eastbourne, New Zealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastbourne,_New_Zealand)?

Answer (score 2):

The order I believe it is the order of Grey Nuns (of the Sacred Heart).

Here is a US branch with an [image](http://www.greynun.org/2016/02/she-intended-to-marry-jackie-donahue-but/) with a similar headpiece.

Here [are a few different orders](http://theraccolta.tumblr.com/post/87561325708/catholic-nuns-of-different-orders-before-the-late) but the leftmost is a Grey Nun with a heart-shaped headpiece.

This is the original posting of that [image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/vintageknittingnet/108223210/) but there aren't any details besides those given by OP.

---

@MattGutting found a nun who disagrees with me (I am not certain in my answer so it is definitely possible). She [says](https://twitter.com/sisterb24/status/935580308208078848):

> Def not Gray Nuns. They have more of a widow's peak looking thing. Could be Sisters of Christian Charity of St Elizabeth w/ modified neck piece. They may be an order unique to the UK, however. The ones that tend to have the "heart" facepiece are usually some form of "Charity" nun.

Comment: On the other hand, at least one nun disagrees - https://twitter.com/sisterb24/status/935580308208078848